# R: how to print character vector to shell in a different encoding?

Tags: r

I have a "funky" character variable coming from a SAS dataset that I imported using the `haven` package in R. This funky character looks like a whitespace e.g.

```
> val
[1] " 11-Mar-2021"...
```

But the result of `grep(' ', val)` returns `integer(0)`. I might guess the apparent whitespace is a special character like a return, a tab, or something, but I'd like to show `val` so that the first entry is "\r11-Mar-2021" or whichever.

Comment: Try `"[:space:]"` instead of `" "`, it matches many things beyond a simple space, including _"tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters"_. See [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) for more details.

Comment: Other options: if you want to remove it, `trimws` by default removes `"[ \t\r\n]"` from both sides. You can't use `"[:space:]"` in `trimws` (that func does not support named classes because it defaults to `perl=TRUE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `iconv(val, from='UTF-8', to='Latin1')` and identified the value has:

```
> val
[1] "\xa011-Mar-2021"
```